# Get a file's root path

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this code to get all the files from a folder and its sub-directories.

```
FolderBrowserDialog fb = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            if (fb.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                foreach (string folder in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(fb.SelectedPath, "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                    listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFullPath(folder));
            }
```

but it returns the file paths like this:
*C:\Users\RANDOM\Desktop\TheSelectedFolder\SubFolder1\Subfolder2\file.txt*
How can i make it return only the name of the Selected Folder plus the path of the sub-directories? without the drive letter, username, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
silliness = Path.Combine( Path.GetDirectoryName(fb.SelectedPath),
                          folder.Replace(fb.SelectedPath, String.Empty)
                         )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use

`System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath)`

where

```
filePath = "C:\Users\RANDOM\Desktop\TheSelectedFolder\SubFolder1\Subfolder2\file.txt"
```

it should return

```
`"C:\Users\RANDOM\Desktop\TheSelectedFolder\SubFolder1\Subfolder2"`
```

From this you can then use a regular expression like **@"^[a-zA-Z]\:\Users\[^]+\"** to cut out the bit of the path you don't want.

Edit: now that my brain is in hear, I can see that the answer I'd give has already been given.

```
Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(selectedFolder),filePath.Replace(selectedFolder,String.Empty))
```

Comment: i want to retrieve only the name of the selected folder + the paths of it's subfolders without the **"C:\Users\RANDOM\Desktop\**